# Constituent type not set when new user with role(s) synchronized as contacts in group(s)

Tags: drupal, contacts

How is the Constituent Type defaulted on user to contact synchronization. I've matched up Drupal roles to contact groups but when I synchronize the user, I get an error on display caused by a missing constituent type. When I added a constituent type for the new user/contact, the problem was fixed. Does the constituent type have to be mandatory? Or is there a default method for constituent types?

Comment: More on the constituent type challenge - it seems constituent type is a required setting when you add a contact directly in civicrm first. When I added another user in drupal first, and did not check any roles, it works ok. But when I add a user in drupal first and select at least one role (beyond authorized), there is a database error, but the user to contact synchronization works anyway but just without the groups added.  Is this a bug?